# How to find the first and last occurrence of date field in a log file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script, logfiles

**log_file:**

```
2021-08-29 23:25:46,398 IST INFO   :......mailslot_create: creating socket for querying route  
2021-08-29 23:25:46,398 IST INFO   :.....mailbox_register: no mailbox necessary for forward  
2021-08-29 23:25:46,398 IST INFO   :......mailslot_create: creating mailslot for route engine - informational socket  
2021-08-30 22:00:00,017 IST  INFO   :.....mailslot_create: creating mailslot for RSVP  
2021-08-30 22:00:00,017 IST INFO   :....mailbox_register: mailbox allocated for rsvp  
2021-08-30 22:00:00,017 IST  INFO   :.....mailslot_create: creating mailslot for RSVP via UDP  
2021-08-31 12:10:41,469 IST INFO   :.....mailslot_create: creating mailslot for RSVP  
2021-08-31 12:10:41,469 IST INFO   :....mailbox_register: mailbox allocated for rsvp  
2021-08-31 12:10:41,469 IST INFO   :.....mailslot_create: creating mailslot for RSVP via UDP  
2021-08-31 12:10:41,469 ISTINFO   :....mailbox_register: mailbox allocated for rsvp-udp  
2021-08-31 12:10:41,469 IST TRACE  :..entity_initialize: interface 127.0.0.1, entity for rsvp allocated and initialized
```

**I want the output to be printed like:**

```
First occurrence of date: 2021-08-29  
Last occurrence of date:2021-08-31
```

Comment: Can we assume every line begins with a date? Can we assume the lines are in sequence?

Comment: Every line may not begin with a date and the lines are in sequence

Comment: If a line does not begin with a date, should we ignore it? Or should we seek for a date later in the line?

Comment: I don't want to ignore the lines without date

Comment: I tried the following and the lines in-between (starting without date) were ignored: `#!/bin/sh  first_occurrence ="$(head -c 10 log_file)"  last_ocuurrence="$(tail -n1 log_file | cut -d' ' -f1)"`

Answer (score 0):

You want a regex for date that can be used for example with `grep`
simple range where `[0-9]` will match one digit value between 0-9

```
grep '20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]' log_file
```

`grep --help` offers some flags

- `-o` filter only match (the date)
- `-m` limit max results

that will give you only first line. btw here `grep` is applied to stdout instead file

```
cat log_file | grep -om1 '20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'
```

that will give you only last line. `tac` is bottom up output here

```
tac log_file | grep -om1 '20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'
```